# WSUS able to differentiate between OS for approved updates?

Tags: wsus

We don't have a big Windows environment, but for the small group of users that do run Windows, they all run slightly different versions (win7, 8.1, 10, etc).

I've modified our WSUS settings to pull in updates for all those OS's but I'm wondering, what will happen in my specific case because we currently do not have very specific update views set up (just a couple views named "Critical Updates" and "Security Updates").

If I were to bulk approve critical/security updates for windows 7, 8.1, and 10 and target our test computer group which houses all the workstations with different operating systems, is WSUS smart enough to only hand out updates that apply to their specific OS to each machine, or would I have to create individual computer groups based on their OS?

Comment: No it is smart enough

Answer (score 3):

> is WSUS smart enough to only hand out updates that apply to their specific OS to each machine

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

WSUS doesn't "hand out" updates, nor does it assign updates or push updates to clients. WSUS allows you to control the Windows Update process on the clients by giving you a method for centrally managing the approval of updates in your environment. The Updates "views" in WSUS have nothing to do with which updates are installed on which clients. The Windows Updates components on the clients determine which of the approved updates are applicable and download and install those updates.

A Windows 7 WSUS client will never install a Windows 8 update because it isn't applicable to that client, no matter how you organize WSUS.

Comment: ahh thank you. Yeah I understand the views have nothing to do with it. I think I just worded the question in an odd way. My question really was what about what you stated in your last sentence there. Just wanted to confirm that the windows update components would be able to differentiate between the updates.